# How to perform conditional statement on XHR

Tags: javascript, ajax

I need to perform a conditional check on the first XHR and if condition is met then execute the second XHR which will use set request header to limit range.

```
function getData( url )
{           
    if  (y==0) { 
    alert ("you set vaue of y to 1");
        var request = new XMLHttpRequest();  
        request.onreadystatechange = function(){
            if ( request.readyState == 4 ){
                renderData( request.responseText );
                request.open( "GET", "TheData.csv", true );
                //request.send( null ); 
                y = 1;
            }     
        }
    } else {
        var request = new XMLHttpRequest();  
        request.onreadystatechange = function(){
            if ( request.readyState == 4 ){
                renderData( request.responseText );
                request.open( "GET", "TheData.csv", true );
                //request.send( null ); 
                request.setRequestHeader("Range", "bytes=" + BytesRead + "-");  
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Are you trying to set the request headers from within the response handler???

Comment: I can get the first alert to process " you set y to 1" but the XHR does not respond?

Comment: y is initiated as a global variable before the XHR and set to 0

Comment: You didn't sent any request. You just created one and set its handler.

Comment: sorry even with the request.send uncommented still does not respond

Comment: The response handler won't get called until the request completes. The request doesn't complete until you send it. You only (try to) send the request within the response handler. That's no good.

Comment: any other ideas? I have already played with the request.send element and still no luck!

Comment: Try sending the request before it completes. That should do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your current logic is as follows:

- do something
- prepare a request
- when the request completes

  - do something with the response
  - send the request

This means that the request won't get sent before its response returns. Logically, the response won't return before you send the request either (Javascript / internet does not support time-loop logic, sorry). This means the request never gets sent. Perhaps you want this:

- do something
- prepare a request
- when the request completes

  - do something with the response
- send the request

Editing your code,

```
function getData( url ){           
    if  (y==0) { 
    alert ("you set vaue of y to 1");
        var request = new XMLHttpRequest();  
        request.onreadystatechange = function(){
            if ( request.readyState == 4 ){
                renderData( request.responseText );
                y = 1;
            }     
            request.open( "GET", "TheData.csv", true );
            request.send( null ); 
       }
    } else {
        var request = new XMLHttpRequest();  
        request.onreadystatechange = function(){
            if ( request.readyState == 4 ){
                renderData( request.responseText );
                request.setRequestHeader("Range", "bytes=" + BytesRead + "-");  
            }
        }
        request.open( "GET", "TheData.csv", true );
        request.send( null ); 
   }
}
```

---

also note you repeat yourself quite a bit. You could shorten your code to

```
function getData( url ){           
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();  
    if (y!=0) { 
        request.setRequestHeader("Range", "bytes=" + BytesRead + "-");  
    }
    request.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if ( request.readyState == 4 ){
            renderData( request.responseText );
            y = 1; //assuming `y` never gets reset to 0
        }
    }
    request.open( "GET", "TheData.csv", true );
    request.send( null ); 
}
```

also note that variables `BytesRead` should be lowercase, not uppercase (=> `bytesRead`), and that you don't need to pass a `null` argument to send (if I read the documentation correctly).

Also note that passing arguments through global variables is a bad practice. In your case, `BytesRead` looks like a global variable (I don't think this is an inner function).

---

Also note that jQuery simplifies the process a bit, even if you use custom headers, should you be willing to use jQuery:

```
function getData(url){
    var headers = {};
    if(y!=0){
        headers.range = "bytes=" + BytesRead + "-"
    }
    $.ajax(url, {
      headers: headers,
      dataType: "text"   //prevent automatic parsing (degression)
    }).done(function(response){
      renderData(response);
      y=1;          
    });
}
```

or even

```
function getData(url){
    $.ajax(url, {
        headers: (y!=0) ? {} : {range : "bytes=" + BytesRead + "-"},
        dataType: "text"
    }).done(function(response){
        renderData(response);
        y=1; 
    }); 
}
```

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/XMLHttpRequest